# Threshold frequency in photoelectric effect

Tags: photons, electrons, collision, photoelectric-effect

If I take a metal sample and I throw light on it, and the emitted photons have frequency less than the threshold frequency required to make an electron come out of that particular metal. So the electron won't come out and photoelectric effect will not be observed.

My doubt is that if the electron absorbs the photon having energy less than the work function of the metal, it must gain some kinetic energy and before it gets hit by another atom or electron, it again gets hit by another photon and in this way many photons are absorbed by it, increasing its kinetic energy till it becomes greater than the work function of the metal, and finally the electron should come out. Why this does not happen? Why there is a minimum frequency of photons to observe the photoelectric effect?

Answer (score 0):

The time for which an electron in excited state with energy less than threshold energy stays in it's excited state could be less than the time taken by another photon to transfer more energy to the already excited electron.
I'm not sure but this could be the reason.